# Any issues with serving non-.css stylesheet extension?

Tags: css

Are there any issues people can think of with using non-standard stylesheet file extensions? i.e. using `.php` or `.less` rather than `.css`?

I'm wondering if there are any issues with old or mobile browsers with this, and if it affects the caching of the file.

Comment: I wouldn't expect any issues as long as mime type is text/css.

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't expect any issues either, though just wondering if there are any edge-case problems etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are either going to have send the header with php
    `header('Content-Type: text/css');`
or configure your server to serve whatever ending you choose as mime/type css.

Either way, any browser should not care what the actual file extensions is, so long as the mime type is correct, and specifies that your file is css.

For less files & nginx - here is a tutorial, for parsing on the fly
[parse less files](http://www.jisaacks.com/parse-less-files-on-the-fly-and-serve-them-as-css)

and for php and less - [here](http://blog.lavoie.sl/2012/11/automatic-less-compilation-with-lessphp.html)